# Assigning a flat JSON object into multiple classes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to figure out a way to assign select properties of the "participants" objects into specific classes:

This is the format that I'm working with

```
"participants": [
    {
        "person_id": "18044029",
        "role_id": "35351535",
        "person_name": "Lella Vignelli",
        "person_date": "Italian, b. 1934",
        "role_name": "Donor",
        "role_display_name": "Donated by"
    },
    {
        "person_id": "18042329",
        "role_id": "35351535",
        "person_name": "Massimo Vignelli",
        "person_date": "Italian, active USA, 1931\u20132014",
        "role_name": "Donor",
        "role_display_name": "Donated by"
    }
]
```

Here are my classes"

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ChObject {

@JsonProperty("participants")
private List<Participation> participants;

//Setters and getters
}
```

Here is the Participation class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Participation {

private Role role;

private Participant participant;
//Setters and getters

}
```

Role class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Role {

@JsonProperty("role_id")
private int role_id;

@JsonProperty("role_name")
private String role_name;

//Setters and getters
}
```

Participant class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Participant {

private int person_id;

@JsonProperty("person_name")
private String person_name;

@JsonProperty("person_date")
private String person_date;

//Setters and getters
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to get the "person_name" and "person_date" properties into the Participant class or the "role_id" and "role_name" properties into the Role class from the Participation class.

The Participation class has access to all of those properties, but I can't seem to assign them to the properties of both the Participant and Roles classes.

Thanks for your help.
Sorry if I'm not 100% clear with everything.

Comment: Your JSON string does not confront to your class structure. In such case, you need to write your own `JSONDeserializer`. Here is a [start](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your class structure needs to match the structure of the JSON document, which is 1 object that contains a single field of type `List<Participant>`, and each `Participant` has those 6 properties.

You can move the data to those other classes that you have, after you de-serialize it correctly.

The correct classes would be:

```
public class ChObject {

    @JsonProperty("participants")
    List<Participant> participants;

    // setters & getter omitted

}

public class Participant {

    @JsonProperty("person_id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("role_id")
    private String roleId;

    @JsonProperty("person_name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("person_date")
    private String date;

    @JsonProperty("role_name")
    private String roleName;

    @JsonProperty("role_display_name")
    private String roleDisplayName;

    // setters & getters omitted

}
```

Also, notice how **it is not necessary to match the java field name with the name of the property**, since you specify its JSON name in the `JsonProperty` annotation.

Comment: +1 to this answer for simplicity, although you can *technically* build it all into the Participation class and use a @JsonSetter method to assign the participation-level properties to the sub-objects manually. Take a look at http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html.

Comment: @Uncommented I didn't know about `@JsonSetter`. I will look into it, thanks :)